# Create file on client side and send to server

Tags: angularjs, file, model-view-controller

i want to create a file in client side using Angular or Javascript and send it to server.
Using MVC controller my server function is

```
 public void SavePivotFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reportsFolder"].ToString(), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Now, in my client side, i have a object that i want to send in SavePivotFile like a file. I tried this but doesnt work. The object 'options' is JSON.

```
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/FileManager/SavePivotFile',
                params: {
                    file: options,
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                showNotification('The changes have been saved.', 'info');
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                showNotification('Failed to save the file.', 'error');
            });
```

Also i tried to create new FormData() before send but also doesn't work. How cat take options JSON object and pass it to server like file?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //C# Code  
   [HttpPost]
   [Route('FileManager/SavePivotFile')]
  // you can use [Allow(Role)] to allow particular role. Google it!   
  public void SavePivotFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reportsFolder"].ToString(), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}



//Angular Code
 $http.post('FileManager/SavePivotFile',options)//Optionsistheobjectuwanttosend 
       .success(function(res){
       //your code. since the c# method isvoid you will not get any response
        })
       .error(function(e){
       //your error handling
        })
```

The HttpPostedFileBase model should be similar to options. That way you can access the JSON in c#.

Let me know if this works.